Issue with EKS Cluster Creation Using `eksctl`
I'm running into an issue while trying to create an EKS cluster using eksctl in AWS. Here’s a quick rundown of the steps I’ve taken and where I’m stuck:
Steps Taken:
Set Up IAM Roles:

Created an InternEKSAccessRole with the required permissions and attached the following policies: AmazonEKSClusterPolicy``AmazonEKSServicePolicy
A custom policy (EKSClusterCloudFormationAccess) allowing iam, cloudformation, ec2, eks, and other necessary services for EKS cluster creation.
Updated the trust relationship for InternEKSAccessRole to allow both my intern user and the EKS service to assume the role:

{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:user/user-intern"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
},
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}

PassRole Policy:
Added a PassRole policy to the InternEKSAccessRole allowing the eksctl commands to pass roles for the cluster’s dynamic service role.
Cluster Creation:
Ran eksctl to create the cluster, but received the following error during the stack creation:
CREATE_FAILED – "Role with arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/eksctl-test-cluster-ServiceRole-<unique-id>, could not be assumed because it does not exist or the trusted entity is not correct."
Problem:
The issue seems to be with the dynamically generated role (test-cluster-ServiceRole-) for the EKS cluster control plane. Despite setting up the InternEKSAccessRole and granting it necessary permissions, the dynamically created role isn't being assumed properly.
Has anyone faced a similar issue with eksctl and the dynamic service roles? Any help or pointers would be appreciated!
What I've Tried:

Checked the trust relationship of the InternEKSAccessRole, which looks correct and includes both my user and the EKS service.
Verified that the PassRole permissions are correctly in place.
The error persists, indicating either the role is not being created or the trust relationship for the dynamic role is incorrect.

What I'm expecting:
Resolution of the Current Error:
I'm trying to solve the issue where the dynamic service role created during the cluster setup is not being assumed correctly by the EKS service. Once resolved, the EKS control plane should be up and running, and the cluster creation process should complete successfully.

Did you check this https://eksctl.io/usage/minimum-iam-policies ? mostly the IAM part
